# How to handle semi-relative include paths with cppcheck

Tags: c++, c++17, static-analysis, cppcheck

Our C++ project is organized in several modules (== subfolders) and headers are placed next to the .cpp files:

```
CMakeLists.txt
src
│
└───folder1
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   MyClass1.h
│       │   MyClass1.cpp
│       │   ...
│   
└───folder2
│   │
│   └───subfolder2
│       │   MyClass2.h
│       │   MyClass2.cpp
│       │   ...
```

Include directives are always defined relative to the folder `src` and not relative to the code file e.g. in MyClass1.cpp:

```
#include "folder1/subfolder1/MyClass1.h" // even the own header is defined semi-relatively
#include "folder2/subfolder2/MyClass2.h"

MyClass1::MyClass1() {
// some code
}
```

I recently noticed that cppcheck (version 1.89) has problems with this and does not correctly

- resolve macros defined in a header file -> False complaints about correct code
- find problems with class member initialization (e.g. `MyClass::MyClass() : _foo(_foo) {}`) -> No complaints about incorrect code

When providing `-I src` to the cppcheck CLI, macros are correctly identified and actual issues like above are found, but analysis time skyrockets from **2 to 20 minutes**.

I suspect, that by providing the whole source code again via `-I`, the files are all re-parsed as header files. Unfortunately, I don't have a specific `include/` sub folder which I can use here. What is advised here? I am already using multiple jobs: `-j 4`.

Comment: Some notes/ideas from my experience with Cppcheck: Header files that are placed directly beside the source file should be found by Cppcheck. You can verify this by using the command line option "--check-config" (nothing else is checked then). Since there is a CMakeLists.txt I assume you use cmake. You can use CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS to create a compile_commands.json which can be used by Cppcheck via the "--project=" option. It should be tested how long the analysis takes then, it could take longer if much more headers are used then.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the header files are included relative to `src`. So it is correct/necessary to specify something like `-I src`.

Comment: @versat Yes, and it actually does work. I just thought it didn't because my checking time skyrocketed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation, this might actually not be a valid question:

1. I manually took all header files and copied them to a separate folder: `find . -type f \( -iname \*.h -o -iname \*.inl -o -iname \*.hpp \) -exec cp --parents \{\} ./../__cppcheckWorkaroundInclude \;` which I then provided via `-I` to cppcheck
2. The check still took 20 minutes, so my assumption that cppcheck wrongfully scans too much is invalid - it actually takes this long because it is a lot of code.
3. So providing `-I __cppcheckWorkaroundInclude` or `-I src` to cppcheck did not make a difference - at least I did not observe one. **Meaning, that `-I` works as expected**

To solve the performance issues (I run the job inside a CI and 20 minutes is a lot of time which I would rather spend on executing automated tests), I did the following:

- Reduce the checked configurations `--max-configs=5`
- Used incremental checking via `--cppcheck-build-dir=CppcheckBuildDir`

To integrate this in our Gitlab CI, I had to cache this directory:

```
  cache:
    paths:
      - CppcheckBuildDir
```

and before the cppcheck call, the directory has to be created (but with the `-p` flag because the dir might already be there, taken from the cache!):

```
mkdir -p CppcheckBuildDir
```

Comment: Regarding the slow analysis: Do you use templates in the code? Are there huge array initializations? I remember that those things could slow down the analysis dramatically in specific versions. You could also try the newer version 1.90 of Cppcheck. I do not remember it exactly but I think there were some performance improvements made for that version.
Is the code open source so we could check what takes so long?
I can also recommend the forum for further discussion: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/

Comment: Yes, the code base uses a lot of templates and different macros. Unfortunately, it is not publicly available. Thanks for looking into this!